# How to get embeddings from long texts without pooling?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I have a collection of relatively long texts, containing roughly 2k tokens each. I want to covert each into an embedding.

I found that [sentence-transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) is quite popular, but it can only take short sequences into account. One approach is to create an embedding for each sentence and then average the results, but I don't want to do that. I'm interested in getting an embedding **without any pooling operations**. I also found [Huggingface's feature extraction pipeline](https://huggingface.co/tasks/feature-extraction), but from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64685243/getting-sentence-embedding-from-huggingface-feature-extraction-pipeline) I understand that it also contains some pooling operator over sequences (unless I'm mistaken).

For example, let's say I want to use a [GPT2 model](https://huggingface.co/gpt2) (or some other model that can take long sequences into account):

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2Model
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model = GPT2Model.from_pretrained('gpt2')
text = "Some very very very long text"
```

Comment: I do not understand how your GPT2 code snippet relates to the question - there are no embeddings there, neither in input nor in output.

Comment: @MrTJ This is just an example of a model that I thought could be potentially used for its long context length. I may be wrong though, it's just the best I could think of

Comment: @Ilya Because I specifically said in the question "without pooling", and you completely ignored that and your answer contains the mean pooling operation: "i use mean pooling operation"